# How to write correct type signature for Vect in Idris?

Tags: dependent-type, idris, purely-functional

Recently I have been exploring dependent types in Idris. However, I overcome to a problem which is quite annoying, which is in Idris, I should start my program with type signature. So the problem is, **How Can I write concise type signature in Idris?**

For example,

```
get_member : (store : Vect n String) -> (idx : List (Fin n)) -> (m : Nat ** Vect m (Nat, String))
get_member store idx = Vect.mapMaybe maybe_member (Vect.fromList idx)
  where
    maybe_member : (x : Fin n) -> Maybe (Nat, String)
-- The below line should be type corrected
-- maybe_member x = Just (Data.Fin.finToNat x, Vect.index x store)
```

If I comment the last line, the compile will type-check the above function,
but if I make the last line as expression, the compile will complain.

```
When checking right hand side of VecSort.get_member, maybe_member with expected type
        Maybe (Nat, String)
When checking an application of function Data.Vect.index:
        Type mismatch between
                Vect n1 String (Type of store)
        and
                Vect n String (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        n1
                and
                        n
```

But I do it as lambda function,

```
get_member : (store : Vect n String) -> (idx : List (Fin n)) -> (m : Nat ** Vect m (Nat, String))
get_member store idx = Vect.mapMaybe (\x => Just (Data.Fin.finToNat x, Vect.index x store)) (Vect.fromList idx)
```

it will be type-check as well.

So the question is, how should I define Vect type with the correct length in the type signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if my explanation is correct, but the following typechecks:

```
get_member : (store : Vect n String) -> (idx : List (Fin n)) -> (m : Nat ** Vect m (Nat, String))
get_member store idx {n} = Vect.mapMaybe (maybe_member) (Vect.fromList idx)
    where
      maybe_member : (x : Fin n) -> Maybe (Nat, String)
      maybe_member x = Just (Data.Fin.finToNat x, Vect.index x store)
```

The difference is that you get the implicit parameter `n` into your scope. This `{n}` and `x: Fin x` refer both to the same `n`. Without pulling the implicit `n` in your scope, idris cannot assume that both `n`s are indeed the same, and it will complain with the error message that it does not know wheter `n1` and `n` are the same.